# Override values in web.xml for jboss eap 6

Tags: rest, web, jboss-eap-6, tomcat5.5

I have a requirement, In case of jboss change the value in web.xml at run time, before deployment. Is there a way to do this?

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.testRest</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Same ear file is used for deployment on all servers, hence need to remove above code from web.xml at run time before deployment on jboss.

If I remove this code, this stops working in dev environment, that deploys application on Tomcat.

Please suggest ways to make it work with both jboss and Tomcat or a way to change web.xml at run time.

Comment: JBoss EAP does not use Jersey so that property won't work unless you replace the JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: How can i remove JAX-RS and implement Jersey in JBoss. I have already removed JAX-RS from my standalone.xml

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head. There are some users who have replaced the JAX-RS implementation. There's probably some information on Google.